# Unable to Check the Lightning challenge

Tags: apex, trailhead

Hi i am working on lightning super badge challenge.Just now unlocked main challenge.But i am unable to check first step.They are asking to rename standard objects.But i have little bit confusion that is whether they are asking to create objects or rename the available objects.

For reference:

**Adventure Package (Opportunity Product object renamed)—vacation, adventure, or excursion associated with a sales opportunity, including the explorer who is taking the adventure and the date of the adventure (use ServiceDate field)**

Adventure (Product object renamed)—Different vacation, adventure, or excursions products sold by Relaxation Gauntlet

Explorer (Contact object renamed)—Prospective or existing customer

Case—One of two record types:

Issues reported by a customer
Issues reported by an expedition leader

But as per your suggestion i had rename the tab.But it still throws an error

For reference:

[image: Opportunity tabs]

Challenge verification

[image: Verification]

Please let me know where i had missed

Answer (score 2):

You can rename Standard Objects under **Customize > Tab Names and Labels > Rename Tabs and Labels**

This doesn't rename the OBJECT necessarily, but it renames the Labels, which would allow you to change the visible name of Contact to Explorer, Product to Adventure, etc. They would then display throughout Salesforce/VF/Lightning with those Labels, even tho they are still the Contact,Product,Case objects on the back end.

Perhaps that is what they are referring to?

Comment: i had updated my question but still i am facing an issue.Please look on it

Comment: I am also facing the same it seems a bug

Comment: don't think it is a bug if others are able to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a new org and trailhead was pointing to different org. Plese, see if that is the case for you as well. make sure both refer to the same org. [image]